# command yarn create react-app issues engine and module

Tags: npm, terminal, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I am trying to create-react-app with typescript as I have done many times to start a new project. It says I have a missing module so I updated my brew, updated yarn, updated node, I see the issue with the engine not compatible with the module but I am not sure how to update the engine either if It deletes everything

```
stephens-MacBook-Pro:MobX stephen$ yarn create react-app mobx_course --template typescript
yarn create v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
warning Pattern ["object-assign@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/Users/stephen/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-object-assign-4.1.1-2109adc7965887cfc05cbbd442cac8bfbb360863-integrity/node_modules/object-assign" as pattern ["object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Installed "create-react-app@4.0.1" with binaries:
      - create-react-app

Creating a new React app in /Users/stephen/Desktop/MobX/mobx_course.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template-typescript...

yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error browserslist@4.14.7: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^6 || ^7 || ^8 || ^9 || ^10 || ^11 || ^12 || >=13.7". Got "13.5.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template-typescript --cwd /Users/stephenbilham/Desktop/MobX/mobx_course has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting mobx_course/ from /Users/stephen/Desktop/MobX
Done.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /usr/local/bin/create-react-app
Arguments: mobx_course --template typescript
Directory: /Users/stephen/Desktop/MobX
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
stephens-MacBook-Pro:MobX stephen$
```

Comment: Did you read the output? It tells you what the problem is: Node 13.5 isn't supported by that package. I'd suggest using an LTS version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `yarn create-react-app ...`?

Notice the - between `create` and `react`.

I believe the convention is to always have it linked with hyphens, e.g.

create-react-app

create-next-app

create-strapi-app

Comment: Hi, My first line is - yarn create react-app mobx_course --template typescript. That was created my the command

Answer (score 0):

To give the solution for this error: you need to make sure your node -v is up to date mine was 13.5 and not compatible anymore so I updated it to 14.5